# Update Wordpress database using LIKE clause

Tags: sql, wordpress, security

I have a bit of a problem, my Wordpress database has been exploited! Within the wp_post table, I have a lot of entries like so

```
<script src='https://hotts.site/site.js?zzz=3' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

I have not use full URL so no one visits it, but its basically the same.  I am trying to remove these from my database.  So far, I have tried

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, "<script src='https://hotts.site/site.js' type='text/javascript'></script>", '') WHERE post_content LIKE '%<script src=\'https://hotts.site/site.js%></script>%';
```

And

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'<script src='https://hotts.site/site.js' type='text/javascript'></script>','');
```

But they both come back with no rows updated.

How am I able to remove all occurences of this tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You really should just delete the posts:

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE "%hotts.site%"
```